# Safari Web Inspector Freezing on tvOS Load

Tags: macos, safari, tvos, tvml, safari-web-inspector

I had a crash in Safari web inspector (Version 9.1 11601.5.17.1) when working on a tvOS (TVML) application, not surprising this happens a fair amount. The problem is now when I attempt to open web inspector for a tvOS application it always crashes. I get nothing, the inspector opens blank with the pinwheel and then I have to force quit.

[image: safari web inspector on crash]

Is there any way to clear out debug data for the web inspector? I am assuming there is something there with that specific application that causes it to crash. Safari is running fine up until I open the web inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, [make sure you are sending crash reports to Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18763), as this helps to ensure that the root problem is identified and fixed. If you have steps to reproduce the crash, it's worth additionally filing a bug report with that information (bugreport.apple.com).

There is a decent chance that the issue may be fixed in upstream WebKit. You can get a newer version by installing the latest [Safari Technology Preview.](https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/)

It's worth noting that System Safari and Safari Technology Preview use separate storage for user settings, including the Web Inspector. **If your hypothesis is correct and the issue is caused by bogus data in Web Inspector's persistent settings, this should clear it up in the short term.** If it continues to crash on first launch, this is probably not the right explanation of the behavior.

Comment: Thanks man, that worked. I wish I knew what crashed it, but I do not know exactly. I am sending my logs to Apple. When doing tvOS development, or anything that is less than a year old, some crashes are expected so I didn't pay real close attention.

Comment: Sorry guys it seems I missed something, so what you are talking about saying "this should clear it" and "that worked" ?